# Why git log --cherry-pick is so slow?

Tags: git, performance, git-cherry-pick

I want to get the changes between two given tags, the command is:

```
git log `Tag1...Tag2 --cherry-pick  --no-merges --right-only
```

but it is very slow.

I test parameters respectively one by one. ONLY when with `--cherry-pick`, git log is very slow.

Why? Anybody could help me out there?

Answer (score 1):

> --cherry-pick
>   Omit any commit that introduces the same change as another commit on the "other side" when the set of commits are limited with symmetric difference.
>
> For example, if you have two branches, A and B, a usual way to list all commits on only one side of them is with --left-right (see the example below in the
>    description of the --left-right option). It however shows the commits that were cherry-picked from the other branch (for example, "3rd on b" may be
>    cherry-picked from branch A). With this option, such pairs of commits are excluded from the output.

It must compare all commits looking for similarities - this will be a very slow operation compared to not having to do any comparison at all.

Comment: Thanks for your response, that is right. I see this man page. however , as it said, we are planning to omit the changes which appear on other branch. Do we have some other ways instead of this?

Comment: If you use merge instead of cherry-pick, you can do this without all the overhead.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but the problem code base is not our work, we just fetch the changes to analyse the quality of some component. we can't control sw developers' behaviors.

Comment: A little confuse. I have already pulled repo to local and command above also run at local. what is your meaning? sorry I dont catch you up.

Comment: Yes.they are from same origin.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using

```
git log tag1 --not tag2
```

Which gives me all commits on tag1 not on tag2. works fine for branches vs tags as well.

Answer (score -1):

Cherry picking could be not so fast, since it's probably detecting renames as part of the merge which can be expensive, especially when you're cherry-picking something which is far away from HEAD.

It may be that your git config has `gc.auto = 0` (`git config --get gc.auto`), so double check if it's enabled, or just run:

```
git gc
```

in order to cleanup unnecessary files and optimize the local repository.

You may also try setting the `merge.renamelimit` config variable to something smaller (e.g. 1, since 0 means *no limit*). If this won't help, try to profile your git (e.g. using `strace` or `perf record git cherry-pick ...`) and find the bottleneck.

See: [cherry-pick is slow](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/cherry-pick-is-slow-td7554198.html)

> For merge-recursive, we would always want to compute the pair-wise 
>   renames between each side and the ancestor. So that diff to the 
>   cherry-pick destination is always going to be an expensive O(# of 
>   changes between source and dest) operation.
>
> Without renames, you could do better on the actual merge with a 
>   three-way tree walk. E.g., you see that some sub-tree is at tree A in 
>   the `ours` and `ancestor` trees, but at tree B in `theirs`. So you don't 
>   have to descend further, and can just say "take theirs" (well, you have 
>   to descend `theirs` to get the values). But I expect it gets more 
>   complicated with the interactions with the index (and is probably not 
>   worth spending much effort on because of the rename issue, anyway).
>
> -Peff